# Tails added Ublock Origin is this as bad as it looks?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, fingerprinting

From my understanding Ublock Origin in Tails will add to the fingerprinting(websites can tell) and it opens up a new attack vector. The filters if compromised could add javascript to any website. Also, someone could think they are improving security and add an HTTP filters on that list which would open them to an attack whether it was comprimised or not. It obviously comes out of date, if someone updates the filters that will add to the fingerprinting(quite possibly you could fingerprint ad blockers by how up to date they are. Did the Tails developers lose their minds?

Tor users also generate revenue for websites by showing ads. If you block ads you add a huge incentive to block Tor users that wasn't there before.

Answer (score 2):

No.

This is no different from the fact that Tails used to ship with AdBlock Plus, it's just a different extension.

Yes, it's fingerprintable but they can only tell you're using Tails.

No, it doesn't open up new vectors. It isn't pulling down updates from the lists, everyone has the same lists, shipped with Tails itself.

No, people should not be pulling down updates or customizing it, that is problematic for all software and exactly why Tails is produced and shipped like it is.

Lots of lazy websites block Tor without even noticing it and for no good reason. Most sites don't care about adblockers anyway because they simply don't constitute a big enough set of their user base. *P.S. death2capitalism.*